# VueJS v-bind filter change input value but not data attached

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to create some filters to use with `v-bind` and not on `{{ }}`. It works if the filter does character to character modifications like uppercase, lowercase, etc. But for things like trim it does't, the input value updates but not the data attached.

Here is an example (https://jsfiddle.net/3nkmjc0c/), I changed the `trim` to a letter change because witespace are not easy to see for test. To reproduce, just type `a` on the input field, the field contains `aZ` but the data still have `a`.

I don't want to use `watchers` because I need it in multiples inputs on different form, it would make like 15 watchers to write. The filter make it reusable. Hope you can help or give an other road to change the input value but keeping it reusable

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is working correctly, just not the way you intended it to. I think this is happening in an order differently than you think.

1. Type in "z"
2. `v-on:input` triggers, which sets `name = z`
3. `name` changed, so Vue updates the value of the input box to `name | trim`
4. `name | trim` is equal to "zA", which displays in the input box
5. `name` *itself* doesn't change again until you type something

Therefore, in one case you're displaying `name | trim` and in another you're displaying `name` and wanting them to be the same.

For what it's worth, this used to work in Vue 1, but they changed it in Vue 2 with no real replacement (except computed properties).

---

If you're trying to just use trim, you can use the `.trim` modifier, like so:

`<input type="text" v-model.trim="name" />`

Or if you want more customization, you'll have to use a computed property:

```
<input type="text" v-model="trimmedName" />

computed: {
    trimmedName: {
    get: function() {
      return this.name
    },
    set: function(value) {
      this.name = value.trim() + "A"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, Vue doesn't support custom form modifiers for some reason, despite a lot of demand. Weigh in here if you think it's an important feature: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3666

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, you are right. And also right about custom modifier, that would solve a lot of my problems...